# VS2008 is slow in a development environment that is disconnected from the internet

Tags: visual-studio-2008, performance

My development environment is disconnected from the internet, and it seems that visual studio 2008 is very slow there. My guess is that the slowness is a result of vs2008 timeouts on attempts to perform internet operations, since on a similar PC that is connected to the internet, vs2008 is much faster.
Does anyone know how can I speed up vs2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations

Especially the point about disabling F1

Comment: Thanks for the reference!
The answer there is about vs2008 in general - are there more solutions for my specific case - when the internet is unavailable?

Comment: Is you environment slow in general or is it for specific actions like startupm shutdown, build, etc... ?